# Stub rest api test negative and positive result

Tags: apex, unit-test, rest-api, rest, stubapi

I have class where using insertData() method and using stub. I want insertData stub return positive and negative results. How can i do it? Inserted data also is another method which I stub. So its like i want to execute stubInsertData twice for status code 200 and  400 (or any another error code).

MockProvider

```
 else if (stubbedMethodName == 'insertData') {
         HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        response.setBody('{"totalSize":0,"done":true,"records":[]}');  
        response.setStatusCode(200);          
        return response; }
```

TestClass

```
 @IsTest
public static void stubInsertData() {
    HttpRequest mockHTTP = (HttpRequest ) 
MockUtil.createMock(HttpRequestService.class);
    Test.startTest();
    mockHTTP.insertData(data);
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

So I want to get 100 coverage  of that part :

```
 HttpResponse res  = obj.insertData(data);
 if(res.getStatusCode == 200)
 //something
 else 
//something
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is called Dependency Injection via the mock's constructor. This allows the mock to tailor its results based on arguments provided when the mock object is constructed.

**Your mock**

```
public class MyMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
 Integer statusCode;  // injected by caller
 MyMock (Integer statusCode) {this.statusCode = statusCode;}

 public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest request) {
   switch on this.statusCode {
      when 200 {
        // create mockresponse for 200
      }
      when 400 {
        // create mockresponse for 400
      }
      when else {...}
    }
   return response;
  }
```

**Invoke in testmethod**

```
// given happy path
.. any setup you need
// when invoked
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MyMock(200));
HttpResponse resp = new myObject().dowWork();
// then verify
.. asserts

// given unhappy path
.. any setup you need
// when invoked
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MyMock(400));
resp = new myObject().dowWork();
// then verify
.. asserts
```